Дискорд бот, создающий тикеты поддержки не видит категорию
Мой дискорд бот для создания тикетов поддержки не видит категорию. Бот еще в процессе написания, поэтому еще нет функционала создания тикета.
У меня есть код:
import discord
import asyncio
import os

os.system("cls")



client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


ticket_guild_id = ***
ticket_menu_id = ***



async def sendMassage(channel_id: int, msg):
    
    print(f"Massage Sended With Text ({msg})")

    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(msg)


async def sendMenu():
    print(f"Menu Opened")

    channel = client.get_channel(ticket_menu_id)

    view = discord.ui.View()

    btn = discord.ui.Button(
        label = "Создать тикет",
        style = discord.ButtonStyle.primary
    )

    btn.callback = createTicket

    view.add_item(btn)

    await channel.send('Для создания тикета нажмите на кнопку <Создать тикет>', view=view)


async def createTicket(self):
    print("Trying To Create Ticket")

    channel = client.get_channel(ticket_menu_id)
    print(channel)

    guild = client.get_guild(ticket_guild_id)
    print(guild)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(sendMenu(), client.loop)


client.run('***') 

Однако при запуске, мне пишет, что категория (guild) равна NoneType, хотя id я получил из самого приложения, нажав на "скопировать id". Что я могу сделать, что-бы получить категорию.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример =>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Также, ознакомьтесь, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Проверьте, есть ли доступ у бота к нужным каналам/категориям, которые вы указываете в коде. Так же на это могут влиять Intents (для большей уверенности используйте discord.Intents.all())

Это может означать, что бот не имеет доступа к серверу с указанным ID или ID был введён неправильно. Проверь что бот добавлен на сервер и имеет права.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
